# Why only define word only with finite product of elements?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

My textbook says that the definition of a word is $(s_1,s_2, s_3 , \dots ) $ where $ s_i\in S\cup S^{-1} $ and $s_i =1 \; $ for all $ i $ sufficiently large.
I don't get that why is this "$s_i =1 \; $ for all $ i $ sufficiently large" part is needed.
Is this because elements which are a infinite products of elements are always same with another finite product of elements?

Comment: Multiplication of words is by concatenation, and how would you concatenate two infinite sequences?

Comment: @MatthewTowers I guess it can't be defined. Hmm,,, So that must be the reason?

Comment: I remember once being told that taking finite products "is almost the definition of algebra!".

Comment: In order for a group $X$ to be free on $S$, any function $f:S \to G$ (with $G$ a group) must lift to $\tilde f:X \to G$. For finite words, it makes sense to take $f(s_1 \cdots s_n) = f(s_1) \cdots f(s_n)$, and everything works out as expected. For infinite words, you'd need some extra machinery for the expected product $f(s_1)f(s_2)\cdots$ to even make sense.

Comment: @anomaly I think I get it. So the problem is that it can't be consistently defined?

Comment: @futuresky The proper way to define a word is as a finite sequence $(s_1,\ldots, s_n)$. I'm not sure why your textbook bothers with infinite sequences only to restrict them. Another problem with "infinite sequence" approach is: what is "$1$" in "$s_i=1$" condition? I assume you start the construction from an arbitrary nonempty set $S$. Where does "$1$" come from? This looks wrong to be honest. What is the textbook you are refering to?

Comment: @freakish It is David S. Dummit's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition, p 216.

Comment: @freakish I don't think its wrong. It emphasises the fact that the $n$ in the finite sequence can vary. In this context, it is common to use $1$ to represent the empty word.

Comment: (Also, the phrase "The proper way to define..." is steeped in bias! What you really mean is "the way I was taught" or "the way I have most frequently seen". There is no "proper" way to do something, and "common" does not mean "best"!)

Comment: @user1729 I'll stick with phrasing my sentences however I want, thank you. As for the real problem: $1$ is not a word, it's an element of alphabet. This is formally incorrect.

Comment: @futuresky so I've looked at the book itself and David Dummit actually takes $S\cup S^{-1}\cup\{1\}$ as the alphabet with $1$ being a "special" character, different from any in $S, S^{-1}$. This makes more sense. Although still more difficult then it should be.

Comment: The context says that "Take a singleton set not contained in $S \cup S^{-1}$ and call it ${1}$". I'm sorry for the incomplete explanation of the context's definition.

Comment: @user1729 also, yes, $n$ varies. As it should, it is the length of the word after all. In the infinite sequence case you now have to define it though. And again by more complicated formula. What is the gain?

Comment: @freakish A concrete benefit of the infinite sequence definition is that it can be viewed as a function from the infinite direct product $(S\cup S^{-1}\cup\{1\})^{\mathbb{N}}$ to the group. Varying the sequence lengths does not easily allow for a function description. I think it is reasonable to consider this to be "the proper" definition, as maths is built on functions. (However, I don't think this is the proper definition, because I do not think we should ever consider a definition to be "the proper" definition.)

Comment: @user1729 Math is not built on functions but on sets. Even functions itself are just special subsets of Cartesian products. And indeed the set of all words is simply $\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{A}^n$ for an alphabet $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all to make that definition formally correct you have to define what $1$ is. Just a special character. Then "$s_i\in S\cup S^{-1}\cup\{1\}$" is what you should have instead of "$s_i\in S\cup S^{-1}$".

> I don't get that why is this "$s_i =1 \; $ for all $ i $ sufficiently large" part is needed.

So this "sequential" approach should be understood as "infinite multiplication". Of course "infinite multiplication" doesn't make much sense (without some additional structure like metric or topology, but that's offtopic) **unless** almost all elements in the infinite multiplication are $1$s. For example

$$2\cdot 3$$

can be written as

$$2\cdot 3\cdot 1$$
or
$$2\cdot 3\cdot 1\cdot 1$$
or
$$2\cdot 3\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots$$

We can "agree" that the last statement makes sense. We can always ignore $1$s. **But** this

$$2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdots$$

doesn't make sense. We don't know how to mulitply infinitely many non-$1$s!

So this is the intuition: a word is a finite sequence filled with infinitely many $1$s.

---

The other thing is that formally this is necessary because later you define so called concatenation of two words. So first if $w=(w_1,w_2,\ldots)$ is a sequence (not necesarily a word) then you define

$$b(w)=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ w_i=1\text{ for all }i> n\}$$
$$len(w)=\begin{cases}
\min(b(w))&\text{if }b(w)\text{ is nonempty}\\
\infty&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The $len(w)$ function should be understood as "the length of sequence $w$". With that the condition "$s_i =1 \; $ for all $ i $ sufficiently large" is equivalent to "$len(s)<\infty$".

The importance of "$len(s)<\infty$" shows when we want to concatenate two words. Have you tried joining two infinite sequences? Not an easy task, maybe even impossible, who knows? It is way easier to join finite sequences. :)

Formally if $w,u$ are two words then the concatenation $wu$ is defined as the word $z$ such that:

$$z_i=\begin{cases}
w_i&\text{if }i\leq len(w) \\
u_{i-len(w)}&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

note that if $len(w)=\infty$ then this definition simply yields $w$. Not interesting. On the other hand $len(u)$ could be infinite but then we would have a problem that $wu$ makes sense but $uw$ not anymore.

**Example.** Say you have two words over $S=\{a,b,c\}$: $w=(a,b,c,1,1,1,\ldots)$ and $u=(c,1,b,b,1,1,1,\ldots)$. Then

$$len(w)=3$$
$$len(u)=4$$
$$wu=(a,b,c,c,1,b,b,1,1,1,\ldots)$$
$$uw=(c,1,b,b,a,b,c,1,1,1,\ldots)$$

Note that there's a special "empty" word $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ all $1$s. For it we have $len((1,1,1,\ldots))=0$.

---

All of that can be approached differently (and in my opinion easier to understand): a word over an alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ is simply a finite sequence $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\in\mathcal{A}^n$. Note that there's a special empty word $()$ which is the only element of $\mathcal{A}^0$. Many things get simplified with this definition. For example the length:

$$len((w_1,\ldots, w_n))=n$$
$$len(())=0$$

Or concatenation:

$$(w_1,\ldots,w_n)(u_1,\ldots,u_m):=(w_1,\ldots,w_n, u_1,\ldots,u_m)$$

with the special rules for the empty word:

$$(w_1,\ldots,w_n)():=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$$
$$()(w_1,\ldots,w_n):=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$$
$$()():=()$$

and so on, and so on. I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's better call this "group word", because "word" has a standard meaning, which does not involve index. Redefining "word" as in the meaning of group word destroys the useful notion of "word".

Second, infinite words involve some subtlety. You may think of words indexed by $\mathbf{N}$, $-\mathbf{N}$, $\mathbf{Z}$, but also by more complicated totally ordered sets, for instance the set of rationals. For instance, let $M_n$ be the monoid on $n$ generators, and let $M_{n+1}\to M_n$ be the identity on the $n$ first generators and map the last generator to the empty word. Then the projective limit of the $M_n$ can be described as the set of pairs $(D,f)$ where $D$ is a (countable) total order, $f$ is a finite-to-one map $D\to\mathbf{N}$, with a obvious identification.

Third, some infinite notions of group words have been considered, for instance in the description of the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring (which is a proper subgroup of the projective limit of free groups). In involves some subtleties that do not occur in the positive case, because of the cancelation phenomena.